# CSS background image being downloaded more than once

Tags: css, firefox

I noticed in my current project that Firefox (3.5.4) downloads the background image (set in CSS) for my divs more than once.

I've checked with both firebug and wireshark and it really does appear that it does not wait for the first request to finish and then simply use the cached version.

Wireshark also confirms that Chrome and IE8 do as expected and only request the image once.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Here is a small test:

[Sample Page](http://nicholasclarke.co.uk/Sprite_Test/)

or

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #one
        {
            height: 300px;
            width:100%;
            background: #FFF url('random.jpg');
        }
        #two
        {
            height: 300px;
            width:100%;
            background: #FFF url('random.jpg');
        }
        #three
        {
            height: 300px;
            width:100%;
            background: #FFF url('random.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

I opened up a bug request as I could not find one already on bugzilla, but it turns out to be an old bug with 3.5.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=497665

Comment: Wow, that is strange. It acts as expected in FF 3.0.15 too, seems there must have been a change of behaviour between the versions. I can't think of any reason why though.

Comment: I have FF 3.5.4 and it only downloaded it once. It went to cache on reload. (Used HTTPFox to view headers.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure your server to allow the browser to cache images.

Comment: Yep done this. Once the image is fully downloaded Firefox uses the cached version.